# Ldap "simple bind" authentication with devise_ldap_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap, ldap-query

I have to configure *devise_ldap_authenticatable* for "simple bind" mechanism, using a username not in the DN form.

For example, with **username=foo.bar,dc=example,dc=com** we use this *ldap.yml* snippet:

```
  host: ldap.example.com
  port: 389
  attribute: username        # it takes the actual value (i.e. foo.bar) from Rails user model
  base: dc=exammple,dc=com
  ssl: false
```

This is like to query the server with `ldapwhoami -D username=foo.bar,dc=example,dc=com -w foo_bar_password`, but I want the *ldap.yml* equivalent to `ldapwhoami -D foo.bar@example.com -w foo_bar_password`.

I didn't find any references about this use case in *devise_ldap_authenticatable*'s documentation.

I would like to know if it is possible to use this Ldap's mechanism with *devise_ldap_authenticatable*; I didn't find any references about this use case in documentation.

Comment: Would it be useful for this purpose *ldap_auth_username_builder*?  If so, how should I proceed?